# What's wrong with this macro definition `\newcommand{\funk}[2]{#1}{-#2}`?

Tags: math-mode

Here is a MnWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\funk}[2]{#1}{-#2}

\begin{document}
    $\funk{x}{2}$
\end{document}
```

It does not compile, giving me the error message:

> You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode. \newcommand{\funk}[2]{#1}{-#

What's wrong with the command?

Comment: As given, the definition of `\funk` is `{#1}`.  The additional braced `{-#2}` is not part of the definition, and thus throws an error, for the use of the `#` token outside of a macro definition. Perhaps you meant `\newcommand{\funk}[2]{#1-#2}
`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes How could I have missed that? How?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [formal specification for `\newcommand`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) is

```
\newcommand*{<cmd>}[<args>][<default>]{<stuff>}
```

where `*` is optional (implies whether the resulting `\def`inition will be `\long` or not), `<cmd>` is a non-existent control sequence, `<args>` (also optional) denote the number of arguments passed gobbled by `<cmd>`, `<default>` is the default value of an optional argument if it is not specified (when `<args>` > 0) and `<stuff>` is the expansion (or replacement text) of `<cmd>` after gobbling the arguments. Each argument (up to 9) is replaced by `#<num>` for the `<num>`th argument (`#1` for the first, `#2` for the second, and so forth).

In your setup

```
\newcommand{\funk}[2]{#1}{-#2}
```

`\funk` takes `2` arguments, both mandatory and the replacement text is just the first argument `#1` (effectively gobbling the second).

`{-#2}` does not form part of the control sequence creation, and therefore is expanded as-is, leaving `-#2` in the input stream (in the preamble), which is not allowed as `#` has special meaning - it's a macro parameter character.

You're probably interested in

```
\newcommand{\funk}[2]{#1-#2}
```

Comment: Or perhaps \newcommand{\funk}[2]{{#1}{-#2}}, if the extra braces are desired (for some reason).